# How to detect key Ctrl+End only outside input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to detect key `Ctrl+End` only outside input field ?

When i press `Ctrl+End` it's will be alert `foo`

And when i click in input field and press `Ctrl+End` I don't want to alert , How can i do ?

http://jsfiddle.net/C7PZB/39/

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('keyup keydown keypress', function(event) {
        console.log(event);
        if(event.keyCode== 35 && event.ctrlKey) {
            alert('foo');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.not("input")`

```js
$(function() {
        $(document).not("input").on('keyup keydown keypress', function(event) {
            console.log(event);
            if(event.keyCode== 35 && event.ctrlKey) {
                alert('foo');
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

But remember there is no `End` key on `MAC` :P

Comment: on MAC , user can goto bottom page using keyboard like windows ? If yes , how can detect ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.is(':input')` to check the element is input or not like following. Hope this will help you.

```js
$(document).on('keyup', function(event) {
    if(!$(event.target).is(':input')){
       if(event.keyCode== 35 && event.ctrlKey) {
           alert('foo');
       }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"/>
```

#### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/C7PZB/41/)